# How to start a postgresql instance for integration testing

Tags: java, postgresql, integration-testing

Usually I use hsqldb for some integration tests and it works fine. But some test need to have a postgresql instance. As our production server run postgresql it is a good idea anyway to run the test against a production database.

Is there a maven plugin or something similar which can easily install and start a postgresql database on a given port and shut it down after all test are run?

Something like [mysql-je](http://mysql-je.sourceforge.net/) for mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testcontainers is the answer. Easy to configure and just does its job. For Postgresql they have a module:

https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/postgres/

And this way you have your test system as close as possible to the production system, which I think is a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of anything. But you probably don't want to start and stop the actual PostgreSQL server; you want to have the server running all the time, and create and destroy databases as needed.

You can [create a database in SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html), and also [destroy it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropdatabase.html). If you set up an initial database that is empty, and not used for storing any data, you can have a workflow like:

1. Connect to the empty database
2. Issue the command to create a new database
3. Run tests against the new database
4. Issue the command to drop the new database

Comment: Step 2) should be "create a new database from a template database. The template database can already contain some test data. Quickest way of initializing a test-environment

Comment: Quite possibly true, but not necessarily. I prefer to have the test database be part of the version-controlled source code, because it needs to change in step with the code (eg when i add a new class, i need to add a new table for it). That means driving the initialisation from a dump file in the project, rather than a template database.

Comment: A hybrid approach we used quite productively on a previous project was to have a template (actually, a server-side dump, because this was with Oracle) which reflected the current state of the production system, and SQL files in the project which captured the changes we wanted to make in the next release. Initialising the database consisted of loading the template/dump, then applying the changes.

Comment: I would not like to have an installed postgresql instance as a prerequisite for my build. hence my question. Thanks for your answer but it doesn't help and is somewhat unrelated to my question.

Comment: @Janning: I see. I don't think i'd recommend doing that; PostreSQL isn't designed to be used that way, but rather to be firmly ensconced in a system. It is really nice to have a build which is capable of downloading all its dependencies on the fly, but there are some dependencies for which that isn't really practical: often things like application servers, database servers, and operating systems. PostgreSQL is one of them, sadly.